# AES Padding issue in iOS but works fine in Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, encryption, aes

I am trying to use AES/CBC encryption in iOS. Decryption is done by C#. Encryption done by Java in Android works fine. I am getting error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." while trying with iOS code. Any help please.

Please find below C#, Java and Objective C code.

C# Code:

```
namespace InternetMobileService
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;


    public class EncryptDecrypt
    {
        //// Replace me with a 16-byte key, share between Java and C#

        /// <summary>
        /// rawSecretKey values
        /// </summary>
        private static byte[] rawSecretKey = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

        /// <summary>
        /// variable field
        /// </summary>
        private ICryptoTransform rijndaelDecryptor;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EncryptDecrypt"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="passphrase">pass phrase</param>
        public EncryptDecrypt(string passphrase)
        {
            byte[] passwordKey = EncodeDigest(passphrase);
            RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
            this.rijndaelDecryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(passwordKey, rawSecretKey);
        }


        public static byte[] EncodeDigest(string text)
        {
            SHA256CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            return x.ComputeHash(data);
        }


        public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                byte[] passwordKey = EncodeDigest(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConstructorKey"].ToString());
                byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(plainText, passwordKey, rawSecretKey);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
            }
        }


        public static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iV)
        {
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            }

            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }

            if (iV == null || iV.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }

            byte[] encrypted;
            using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijAlg.Key = key;
                rijAlg.IV = iV;
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
                using (MemoryStream memorystreamEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptostreamEncrypt = new CryptoStream(memorystreamEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter streamwriterEncrypt = new StreamWriter(cryptostreamEncrypt))
                        {
                            streamwriterEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }

                        encrypted = memorystreamEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            return encrypted;
        }


        public string Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData)
        {            
            byte[] newClearData = this.rijndaelDecryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newClearData);
        }


        public string DecryptFromBase64(string encryptedBase64)
        {
            return this.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedBase64));
        }
    }
}
```

Java Code:

```
public class Crypto {
    public static final String TAG = Crypto.class.getSimpleName();
    // Replace me with a 16-byte key, share between Java and C#
    private static Cipher aesCipher;
    private static SecretKey secretKey;
    private static IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
    private static String CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static byte[] rawSecretKey = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

    private static String MESSAGEDIGEST_ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";

    public Crypto(String passphrase) {
        byte[] passwordKey = encodeDigest(passphrase);

        try {
            aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No such algorithm " + CIPHER_ALGORITHM, e);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No such padding PKCS5", e);
        }

        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passwordKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(rawSecretKey);
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] clearData) {
        try {
            aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] decryptedData;

        try {
            decryptedData = aesCipher.doFinal(clearData);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return decryptedData;

    }

    public String decryptAsBase64(byte[] clearData) throws IOException {
        byte[] decryptedData = decrypt(clearData);
        return new String(Base64New.decode(decryptedData));
    }

    public String encryptAsBase64(byte[] clearData) {
        byte[] encryptedData = encrypt(clearData);
        return Base64New.encodeBytes(encryptedData);
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] clearData) {
        try {
            aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key", e);
            return null;
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid algorithm " + CIPHER_ALGORITHM, e);
            return null;
        }

        byte[] encryptedData;
        try {
            encryptedData = aesCipher.doFinal(clearData);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Illegal block size", e);
            return null;
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Bad padding", e);
            return null;
        }
        return encryptedData;
    }

    private byte[] encodeDigest(String text) {
        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGEDIGEST_ALGORITHM);
            return digest.digest(text.getBytes());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No such algorithm " + MESSAGEDIGEST_ALGORITHM, e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Obj C Code:

```
+ (NSString*)encryptBase64String:(NSString*)string keyString:(NSString*)keyString separateLines:(BOOL)separateLines
{

    const unsigned char rawSectret[] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    NSData* rawScretdata = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawSectret length:kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    NSString *shaKeyString = [self sha256HashFor:keyString];

    NSData *sourceData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *ivString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawScretdata
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSData* Outdata = [sourceData AES128EncryptedDataWithKey:shaKeyString  iv:ivString];


    NSString *encodedString = [Outdata base64EncodedStringWithSeparateLines:separateLines];

    return encodedString;
}

- (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
    if (iv) {
        [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: You're obviously not using AES-128 (obj-c), but rather AES-256, because the key is derived from the password with SH-A256. `rawSecretKey` is the byte array for the IV, so the name is misleading. The key derivation from a password needs to be much stronger like PBKDF2 with a million iterations and a random salt. Also, you're not authenticating your ciphertexts with HMAC.

Comment: If it is a padding issue only the last block will be incorrect. Essentially PKCS5Padding and PKCS7Padding are the same, it is just that the documentation of PKCS7Padding allows for larger block sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Common Crypto used an explicit key size, many other libraries use a key size based on the supplied key so you need to make sure you specify the correct key size for Common Crypto, one of `kCCKeySizeAES128`, `kCCKeySizeAES192`, `kCCKeySizeAES256`, not `kCCBlockSizeAES128`. In this case since the key is derived with SHA-256 `kCCKeySizeAES256` is the keysize that should be specified.

C# is using Rijndael so you must be sure you specify a block size of 128, the only block size AES supports.

Simply if you get the input the same the outputs will match. They are options (mode and padding), key, keysize, data and iv. Check them in hex.

Supply test vectors: key, input data and output data in hex for all three so we can test the code.

Comment: Where should I change? I can see multiple occurrences of kCCBlockSizeAES128

Comment: You use `kCCBlockSizeAES128` where a block size is required, `kCCKeySizeAES256` (or other appropriate size) where a key is required. See the CCCrypt documentation (header file).